# Oracle 11g - Database Job About User Lock

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, jobs, scheduled-tasks

I have an Oracle database (Oracle 11gR2) and I want to create a job. The job will trigger my procedure.

The procedure must comply with the rules I have specified below:

- If a user's expiry_date value is EXPIRED (select username, account_status, lock_date, expiry_date from dba_users where account_status='EXPIRED';), it will lock this user.
- If a user's expiry_date value is EXPIRED and if it is already lock state, it will not do anything.
- Exclude internal schemas for this operation.

I searched it but I didn't find any clear solution for it.

How can I create this procedure?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure p1 as
begin
  for u in (select username from dba_users where account_status in ('EXPIRED', 'EXPIRED(GRACE)') and username not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', '...'))
  loop
    execute immediate 'alter user "' || u.username || '" account lock';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

For 12c and higher you could use the `ORACLE_MAINTAINED='N'` for filtering the built-in users instead of the `IN-list`.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your help. About 15 minutes ago to your response, I created a procedure like this and it runs successfully. And also your response is a true. Thank you again.